# Ajuda com barra de progresso!

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Olá, bom dia, gostaria de saber se alguém já viu ou ja implementou uma barra de progresso ao dar scroll na pagina.
uma barra que fica fixa abaixo com um botão de avançar

mais ou menos isso..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
var sections = $('.panelSection');
console.log(sections);
var i =0;
var scrolto = 0;

function next(){

    if(i == 0){
        $('.prev-section').show();
    }
    if(i < sections.length -1){
        i++;
        
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: sections[i].offsetTop
        }, 2000);
    }
}
function prev(){
    if(i == sections.length -1){
        $('.next-section').show();
    }
    if(i > 0){
        i--;
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: sections[i].offsetTop
        }, 2000);
    }    
}
$('html').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == '38'){
        prev();    
    }
   if(e.which == '40'){
        next();    
    }
});
$('.next-section').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   next();
});
                         
$('.prev-section').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   prev();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    
    section{height: 100vh;text-align: center; font-size: 30pt}    
    
</style>

<section class="panelSection">
INICIO
</section>

<section class="panelSection">
TOPICO 1
</section>
    
<section class="panelSection">
TOPICO 2
</section>

<footer>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="footer-body">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    
                    <li><a href="#" class="next-section">Next Section</a></li>
                   
                </ul>   
            </div>
            
           <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#footer-body">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <li><a href="#" class="next-section">Next Section</a></li>
                   
                </button>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Basicamente é isso, porem preciso que vá preenchendo as bolinhas, como se fosse uma timeline mas na vertical

obs: eu não fiz nenhum teste ainda, só queria uma ajuda, se alguém poder ajudar agradeço muito.

Comment: Tem codigo ja amigo? Joga no JSFiddle

Comment: A barra que você quer é a bolinha azul avançando para a direita?

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e dê mais detalhes  do que você precisa, está meio vago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode trabalhar com um mix do evento [onScroll](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp) com a propriedade [scrollTop](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp)

Para descobrir o tamanho máximo do Scroll, o melhor meio que achei foi:

```
document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

Todos outras referencias que achei na internet o resultado sai meio esquisito...

Para definir em qual posição o Scroll está basta utilizar `document.body.scrollTop`

```js
window.onscroll = function(){
  var posicaoScroll = document.body.scrollTop;

  document.getElementById("scrollTotal").value = posicaoScroll;

}

window.onload = function(){
  var tamanhoScrol = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  document.getElementById("scrollTotal").max = tamanhoScrol;
}
```

```html
<body id="testeScroll" style="height:2050px"></body>
<input id="scrollTotal" type="range" style="position:fixed;" value="0">
```